# Login with facebook and retirve data

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm using facebook api to login the user, it's working fine but i'm having some troubles to retrieve data and use on code behind. I've tried some solutions but nothing worked.

Here the code so far

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        // Load the SDK Asynchronously
        (function (d) {
            var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
            if (d.getElementById(id)) { return; }
            js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
            js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
            ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
        } (document));

        // Init the SDK upon load
        window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
            FB.init({
                appId: 'MY_APP_ID',
                channelUrl: 'MY_URL',
                status: true,
                cookie: true,
                xfbml: true
            });

            FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
                if (response.status === 'connected') {
                    // connected
                } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
                    // not_authorized
                } else {
                    // not_logged_in
                }
            });
        }
        function login() {
            FB.login(function (response) {
                if (response.authResponse) {
                    retrieveInfo();
                    window.location.reload();

                } else {
                    // cancelled
                }
            });

        }

        function retrieveInfo() {
            FB.api('/me', function (response) {

                var name = document.getElementById('name');
                name.innerHTML = response.name;

                var email = document.getElementById('email');
                email.innerHTML = response.email;

            });
        }
</script>

<fb:login-button onlogin="login()" perms="email,user_about_me,user_birthday">Login com Facebook</fb:login-button>

<div align="center">
    <div id="name"></div>
    <div id="email"></div>
</div>
```

As i said the data is been retrieved ok, but how can i use it on code behind?

Comment: `FB.api` is an _asynchronous_ method – that means, the following code is executed immediately, execution does not wait for this method to finish. And for your code that means, you are reloading the page immediately after calling retrieveInfo, and that’s of course before the API request is finished.

Answer (score 1):

Once you established a user is logged in, you can use the [Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/).  On the server, you can make an HTTP REST request to one of the URL's defined in that document, and receive the results.

You could create using [HttpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx), or the new .NET 4.5 [HttpClient](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/henrikn/archive/2012/02/16/httpclient-is-here.aspx) class.